# Index the result of a query to join

Tags: mysql, database, join, optimization

I need to know if it is possible to index the result of a subquery in order to join with another result.
I have the query:

`Select A.*, B.* from (select * from table1 where condition1 = 1) A join
(select * from table2 where condition2 = 0) A on
A.c1 = B.c1 and A.c2 = B.c2`

I assume that i need to index the results of the subqueries to improve the speed of the response:

```
select * from table1 where condition1 = 1 (Id like to index the fields c1, c2)

select * from table2 where condition2 = 0 (Id like to index the fields c1, c2)
```

is this possible? I wanna do it by indexing the subqueries.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no use in having an index on a subquery. Computing the index would require scanning the entire result of the subquery anyways, so there is no benefit.

However, if the result of your subquery changes very infrequently, you could add another table which stores the intermediate result and add an index to that table. If the data in `table1` or `table2` is updated, make sure to update the additional table as well. An automatic update can be achieved using triggers.

Comment: When i execute the join query, it takes more than 40 minuts. The result of the two queries have 70000 records. I believe there must be a way to index the two results before execute the join. In foxpro it takes less than five minuts, im sure that i need to index them.

Comment: As I said, you can add additional tables to store your subqueries and add an index on those tables. But adding an index to a subquery just does not make sense.

Comment: Andy thanks for the response. Please, forget if it make no sense, is possible to index?

Comment: The fine people who made MySQL know that there is no benefit in adding indexes to subqueries and, therefore, it is not possible. Again, you have to create another table for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table with your inner query and index it and then use your outer query on the temp table.

[Create index on temp table](http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/create-index-on-temp-table)

[When to Add Indexes to temp tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10993/51121)